# How to handle lots of 'archived' data in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

We have a huge Postgres database where we store fiscal data (invoices, bank statements, sales orders) for thousands of companies. In the UI of our app the data is divided per fiscal year (which is 1 calendar year most of the times). So a user chooses a year and only sees data for that specific year.

For example we have a table that stores journal entries (every incoice line can result in multiple journal entries). This table is quite slow on the more complex queries. It's one big table going like 15 years back. However, users rarely access old data anymore. Only the past 2 or 3 years will be actively accessed, data older than that will almost never be accessed.

What is the best way to deal with this old, almost archived data? Partitioning? Clustering? If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be of great help.

Ps. our database is hosted in Google Cloud

Comment: How is the data arranged in the table?  Is new data added in "real time" (the year/timestamp column nearly corresponds to the actual year/time it was inserted) or do you get backfilling, where historical data gets added long after the fact?

Comment: It would be very helpful to see some `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for some selected slow queries.  Turn track_io_timing to ON first if it is not already on.

Comment: We do have lots of historical data getting inserted, however, rarely older than 1year.. I am going to dive into the queries. It's a bit though since we use a framework that generates the queries based on a security and domain configuration. So we now we have sub-optimal queries here and there but we cannot overwrite to a custom query..